# reshaping df into multindex and concatenating along keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called "df1":

```
            0     1      2      
2015-10-13  96    97.0   59.0   
2008-03-18  90    91.0   92.0
```

and would like to reshape it to :

```
             0         
2015-10-13   96   
             97.0    
             59.0   

2008-03-18   90   
             91.0    
             92.0
```

Furthermore, I have a second df called "df2" , which has the same index as df1, but different values , and I'd like to concatenate them on along each key to have a final output like this:

```
             0        1    
2015-10-13   96       93
             97.0     105
             59.0     123

2008-03-18   90       26
             91.0     36
             92.0     45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you there, if you're OK with an extra level in the index:

```
import pandas

data = {'0': {'2008-03-18': 90, '2015-10-13': 96},
        '1': {'2008-03-18': 91.0, '2015-10-13': 97.0},
        '2': {'2008-03-18': 92.0, '2015-10-13': 59.0}}

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df2 = df1

result = pandas.concat([df1.stack(), df2.stack()], axis=1)
```

result is

```
                 0     1
2008-03-18 0  90.0  90.0
           1  91.0  91.0
           2  92.0  92.0
2015-10-13 0  96.0  96.0
           1  97.0  97.0
           2  59.0  59.0
```

As mentioned by @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in the comments, you can get rid of the extra level in the index by using

```
flat_result = result.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Comment: A  `.reset_index(level=1, drop=1)` should get rid of that extra level.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with define new column names by parameter `keys` + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=(0,1)).stack()
#data borrowed from another answer
print (df3)

                 0     1
2008-03-18 0  90.0  90.0
           1  91.0  91.0
           2  92.0  92.0
2015-10-13 0  96.0  96.0
           1  97.0  97.0
           2  59.0  59.0
```

---

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('a','b')).stack()
print (df3)

                 a     b
2008-03-18 0  90.0  90.0
           1  91.0  91.0
           2  92.0  92.0
2015-10-13 0  96.0  96.0
           1  97.0  97.0
           2  59.0  59.0
```

And for remove second level of index add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=(0,1)).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
print (df3)

               0     1
2008-03-18  90.0  90.0
2008-03-18  91.0  91.0
2008-03-18  92.0  92.0
2015-10-13  96.0  96.0
2015-10-13  97.0  97.0
2015-10-13  59.0  59.0
```

Comment: nice I like the drop=True better than drop =1

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list comprehension into a `numpy.column_stack`.  Then pass the result to `pd.DataFrame`

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([d.values.ravel() for d in [df1, df2]]),
    df1.index.repeat(df1.shape[1])
)

               0      1
2015-10-13  96.0   93.0
2015-10-13  97.0  105.0
2015-10-13  59.0  123.0
2008-03-18  90.0   26.0
2008-03-18  91.0   36.0
2008-03-18  92.0   45.0
```